# Show asymptotic orthogonality of eigenvectors

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, convergence-divergence, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

Let $(A_n),(B_n)$ be sequences of $n\times n$ (growing size) matrices. Suppose also that

$$\lambda_1(A'_nA_n) \to c>0 \hspace{1cm} \text{as} \hspace{1cm} n\to \infty$$

$$\lambda_1(B'_nB_n) \to 0 \hspace{1cm} \text{as} \hspace{1cm} n\to \infty$$

where $\lambda_1$ denotes the largest eigenvalue. Let $Q_n$ and $R_n$ be the $n\times 1$ normalized eigenvectors associated to the largest eigenvalue of $A'_nA_n$ and $B'_nB_n$ respectively. Am trying to prove that

$$Q_n'R_n\to 0 \hspace{1cm} \text{as} \hspace{1cm} n\to \infty$$

Is this possible? Any ideas on how to proceed is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need more qualifications for this to hold. Set
$$A_n = \text{diag}(1, 0, \cdots,0)$$
Then for each $A_n$, we have that $\lambda_1(A_n ' A_n) = 1$, and the corresponding eigenvector is $\hat{e}_1$. Now set
$$B_n = \text{diag}(1/n, 0, \cdots, 0)$$
Then for each $B_n$, we have that $\lambda_1(B_n' B_n) = 1/n^2 \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. But the corresponding eigenvector is also $\hat{e}_1$, so it will always be the case that $Q_n' R_n' = 1$.

Comment: What if I permute the columns of $B_n$ in a random fashion each time before computing $B'_nB_n$? Can I show that $Q_n'R_n$ converge to $0$ in probability?